# Treat list like fwf and import into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in a file that looks like the following:

```
headerfilewithlotsofinformationthatcanbediscarted@!123456789LASTNAME FIRSTNAME987654321123456789@!7418529630LASTNAME FIRSTNAME7895456423156498456@!...
```

Using Python's .split() method, I can separate the file in a more useful format which returns a list, like this:

```
headerfilewithlotsofinformationthatcanbediscarted
123456789LASTNAME FIRSTNAME9876543211234567895
741852963LASTNAME FIRSTNAME7895456423156498456
...
```

As you can see, each element in the resulting list is a fix-width-file-like structure. From there, I need to further separate each row into the corresponding value (I'll manually set the names and width of the columns needed in advanced in a list) and create a DataFrame:

```
         ID               Name    COL1   COL2   COL3
0 123456789 LASTNAME FIRSTNAME 9876543 211234 567895
1 741852963 LASTNAME FIRSTNAME 7895456 423156 498456
...
```

**Question is, how can I treat each row of the list (or the whole list for all that matters) as a fixed width value in pandas to convert it to the DataFrame?**

The equivalent of achieving this if I were reading the data directly from a fix-width file would be something like:

```
pd.read_fwf(file, colspecs = [(0,11),(11,50)...], header = None, names = ("ID", "Name"...)
```

I tried to load the file directly on a pandas DataFrame and use pandas to separate it (split it) into rows, but it seemed pretty slow (pandas took around 30s, Python less than 0.2s, for around 100,000 rows). Although that does let me use the previous code to get the columns that I need.

Comment: how you separated those numbers in to col1, col2 and col3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after you split():

```
colspecs = 0, 9, 18, 26, 33, 40, 47
df = pd.DataFrame([[row[i:k] for i, k in zip(colspecs[:-1], colspecs[1:])] for row in split_list[1:]])
```